# Quotient of Riemann surface by properly discontinuous group action

Tags: reference-request, group-actions, riemann-surfaces, quotient-spaces

I am looking for a reference on quotients of Riemann surfaces by properly discontinuous group actions.

In particular, I would like a reference for the following result: Let $M$ be a Riemann surface and let $G$ be a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(M)$ whose action on $M$ is properly discontinuous. Then the quotient space $M/G$ has the structure of a Riemann surface, and the projection map $\pi\colon M\to M/G$ is holomorphic.

Edit: My definition of "properly discontinuous" is that for any compact subset $K$ of $M$, the set $\{g\in G:K\cap g(K)\neq\varnothing\}$ is finite.

Comment: The charts for $M$ are charts for $M/G$ there is nothing to prove

Comment: aren't there problems at the points where the isotropy groups are nontrivial (where $gm=m$ for some nontrivial $g$?

Comment: Those points appear in discrete action, to me properly discontinuous is when there are no such cases (I'd say for discrete action, since meromorphic on $M/G$ implies meromorphic on $M$, you can use the set of $G$-invariant functions meromorphic around $p\in M$ to construct a chart for $G.p$, discrete action means there are non-constant ones and the one with least order $0$ is a chart)

Comment: there are several different conventions for these definitions, I think. I have seen my definition referred to as "properly discontinuous" in several places.

Comment: So do you see what I mean with the $G$-invariant meromorphic function with zero of least order at $p$ ? Take a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p \in M$ and the $g\in G$ such that $g.p=p$, there are finitely many $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ which is a finite group and we are considering the set of functions analytic on $U_p$ that are $g_1,\ldots,g_k$-invariant. There is always $\prod_j f(g_j.z)$ so this set is non-empty. The one with least order zero at $p$ (probably of order $k$ thus $\prod_j f(g_j.z)$ for $f$ with a simple zero at $p$) is a chart $U_p/G \to \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: I understand why this should work, but I don't see how to prove that the $g_1,\ldots,g_k$-invariant function with the smallest order zero at $p$ gives a chart $U_p/G\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Take $f$ with a simple zero at $p$ and $F(z)=\prod_j f(g_j.z)$. At the $z$ close to $p$ a chart is just the identity $M \to M/G$. This is because the zeros of $F'$ (where $F'$ depends on a chart around $z\in M$ but its zeros are chart independent) are isolated thus for $z$ close enough to $p$, $\forall g \in G, g.z \ne z$. And $F$ is locally biholomorphic at those $z$, in particular it is biholomorphic to the identity charts. This way we have defined a Riemann surface whose points are $\{ G.z,z\in M\}$ and such that $M \to M/G$ is holomorphic

Comment: About the meromorphic function with zero of least order : making $M/G$ a Riemann surface means defining a complex structure which means defining its (locally) analytic/meromorphic functions, those objects are equivalent. And "$M \to M/G$ is holomorphic" is the same as "a function analytic at some point of $M/G$ is analytic at the corresponding points of $M$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, you might want to take a look at Theorem 6.2.1. in Beardon's Geometry of Discrete Groups:

Theorem 6.2.1. Let $D$ be a subdomain of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ and let $G$ be a group of Möbius transformations which leaves $D$ invariant and which acts discontinuously in $D$. Then $D/G$ is a Riemann surface.

Beardon gives a detailed proof over several pages.

Chapter III Section 3 of Miranda - Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces might also be interesting as well as Theorem 5.9.1 in Jones & Singerman - Complex Functions. Here the second part is also shown.

Non of these sources contain the exact statement you are looking for, but may contain ingredients for a proof.